# Is $(On,\in)$ + $(On, \in)$ a well-order?

Tags: summation, ordinals, well-orders

the definition of a well-order we were given is that it is a left-narrow, well-founded linear order.
Therefore $(On,\in)$ is a well-order.
Furthermore we were said that the sum of two well-orders (which is basically glueing them together one after another) is also a well-order, but as I see it $(On,\in)$ + $(On, \in)$ is not left-narrow anymore.

Is there another definition or am I missing something else?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "left-narrow" mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ context, unless otherwise specified **all** mathematical structures - topological spaces, linear orders, rings, groups, etc. - are *sets*. $(On,\in)$ is therefore not even a *linear* ordering since it's too big: it's a proper class. Meanwhile, you can prove that the sum of two well-orderings is again a well-ordering (a key point being that the union of two sets is always a set).

However, it sounds like your text is using a slightly odd approach here. "Left-narrow" [appears to mean](https://books.google.com/books?id=hwrmDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA96&lpg=PA96&dq=%22left-narrow%22+%22well-ordering%22&source=bl&ots=3COHinee1z&sig=ACfU3U2d28iW9drGZsfDr8UBX3lAMAK6dg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk79f24L_vAhWKAZ0JHfQWBv4Q6AEwAXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%22left-narrow%22%20%22well-ordering%22&f=false) that every proper initial segment should be set-sized; under this definition, $(On,\in)$ *is* a well-ordering. This is **not standard** per the above, but if this is what your text is doing, then yes, $(On,\in)+(On,\in)$ is not a well-ordering anymore; indeed, $(On,\in)+{\bf 1}$ isn't a well-ordering! (Which is a good sign that we shouldn't include it.)

---

It's worth noting that we can talk - to a certain extent anyways - about "class-sized versions" of many kinds of mathematical structures. The issue *(as long as we don't [go to some class theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory) to simplify things)* is that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ can't quantify over classes, so things like "Given any two class-well-orderings, one is isomorphic to an initial segment of the other" can't even be *expressed* in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, let alone *proved*.

Now the situation isn't *entirely* negative. We can talk about specific examples. Going back to the OP, the class $On\times\{0,1\}$ is definable by a formula $\psi$, and the relation $$(\alpha,i)\trianglelefteq (\beta,j)\quad\iff\quad i<j\mbox{ or }[i=j\mbox{ and }\alpha\le\beta]$$ on that class is definable by a different formula $\varphi$; intuitively, the pair $(\psi,\varphi)$ define "$On+On$." We can then prove, in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, that this class-sized "structure" has no infinite descending chains - that is, it's a class-well-ordering. With more work we can quantify over class-well-orderings whose defining formulas have bounded complexity [in a precise sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_hierarchy).

But all of this is significantly messier than the "sets-only" situation, and most of the time is worth avoiding.

Comment: Thank you very much!